# Calculating the forecasts by month for the last 3 months in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called forecasts where we store the forecasts for all the products for the next 6 months. For example when we are in November we create the forecast for December, January, February, March, April and May. The forecasts table looks something like the one below

```
+----------------+---------------+--------------+----------+
| product_number | forecasted_on | forecast_for | quantity |
+----------------+---------------+--------------+----------+
| Prod 1         | 2016-11-01    | 2016-12-01   |      100 |
| Prod 1         | 2016-11-01    | 2017-01-01   |      200 |
| Prod 1         | 2016-11-01    | 2017-02-01   |      300 |
| Prod 1         | 2016-11-01    | 2017-03-01   |      400 |
| Prod 1         | 2016-11-01    | 2017-04-01   |      500 |
| Prod 1         | 2016-11-01    | 2017-05-01   |      600 |
+----------------+---------------+--------------+----------+
```

Where the table contains a list of product numbers and the date on which the forecast was created i.e. forecasted_on and a month for which the forecast was created for along with the forecasted quantity.

Each month data gets added for the next 6 months. So when the forecasted_on is 1-December-2016 forecasts will be created for January till June.

I am trying to create a report that shows how the total forecasts have varied for the last 3 months. Something like this

```
+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|            | 0 months prior | 1 month prior | 2 months prior |
+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| 2016-12-01 |            200 |           150 |            250 |
| 2017-01-01 |            300 |           250 |            150 |
| 2017-02-01 |            100 |           150 |            100 |
+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Currently I am using a lot of repetitive code in rails to generate this table. I wanted to see if there was an easier way to do it directly using a SQL query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use PIVOT query:

```
select forecast_for, 
       sum( case when forecasted_on + interval '1' month = forecast_for 
            then quantity end ) q_0,
       sum( case when forecasted_on + interval '2' month = forecast_for 
            then quantity end ) q_1,
       sum( case when forecasted_on + interval '3' month = forecast_for 
            then quantity end ) q_2,
       sum( case when forecasted_on + interval '4' month = forecast_for 
            then quantity end ) q_3,
       sum( case when forecasted_on + interval '5' month = forecast_for 
            then quantity end ) q_4,
       sum( case when forecasted_on + interval '6' month = forecast_for 
            then quantity end ) q_5
from Table1
group by forecast_for
order by 1
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30e5e/1

```
|               forecast_for |    q_0 |    q_1 |    q_2 |    q_3 |    q_4 |    q_5 |
|----------------------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| December, 01 2016 00:00:00 |    100 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  January, 01 2017 00:00:00 | (null) |    200 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| February, 01 2017 00:00:00 | (null) | (null) |    300 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|    March, 01 2017 00:00:00 | (null) | (null) | (null) |    400 | (null) | (null) |
|    April, 01 2017 00:00:00 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |    500 | (null) |
|      May, 01 2017 00:00:00 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |    600 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `(product_number, forcast_on, forcasted_for)` is unique (so no aggregation is required), then this should do the job:

```
WITH forecast_dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT product_number, forcast_for
    FROM forecasts
)
SELECT
  fd.forcast_for AS "forecast for",
  m1.quantity    AS "one month prior",
  m2.quantity    AS "two months prior",
  m3.quantity    AS "three months prior"
FROM forecast_dates fd
  LEFT JOIN forecasts m1 ON fd.forcast_for = m1.forcast_for AND fd.forcast_for = m1.forcasted_on + INTERVAL '1 month'
  LEFT JOIN forecasts m2 ON fd.forcast_for = m2.forcast_for AND fd.forcast_for = m2.forcasted_on + INTERVAL '2 month'
  LEFT JOIN forecasts m3 ON fd.forcast_for = m3.forcast_for AND fd.forcast_for = m3.forcasted_on + INTERVAL '3 month'
WHERE fd.product_number = 'Prod 1'
ORDER BY fd.forcast_for;
```